# Service Locator Anti-Pattern Okay For Factory Registration

Tags: c#, rest, dependency-injection, .net-core, service-locator

I'm creating a REST framework,  and I'm wondering if it's okay to provide access to the service provider since it will be used in the Factory.  I have a generic service which has events that fire on Create and Update

```
public event Func<object, TDTO, Task> CreateEvent;

protected virtual async Task OnCreated(TDTO dto)
{
    await ServiceEventHandlerRule.OnServiceEvent(CreateEvent, this, dto);
}

public async Task<TDTO> Create(TDTO dto)
{
    var entity = this.DtoToEntity(dto, new TEntity());
    this._context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);

    dto = await this.SaveEntity(entity);
    await OnCreated(dto);
    return dto;
}
```

I'm registering Events on my sevices in a factory, Currently I'm exposing a `Func<IServiceProvider, Object, TDto>`  Event Registration looks like so, this occurs in my startup.cs:

```
var serviceConfig = new ServiceConfiuration<User, UserDTO>();
serviceConfig.EventMapping.AddCreateEvent(async (sp, obj, dto) => {
    var hubTaskQueue = sp.GetService<IHubServiceTaskQueue>();
    hubTaskQueue.QueueCreate<THub, TDTO>(dto);
});
services.AddScopedRestService(serviceConfig);
```

Users will need access to a few extra dependencies for their events so I've given them access to the `IServiceProvider`,

What is the downside of using the Service Location Pattern During Registration?

Should I mask IServiceProvider and make a few Generic Overload which will auto resolve their dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl), we define Service Locator as:

> A **Service Locator** supplies application components outside the **Composition Root** with access to an unbounded set of **Volatile Dependencies**. *[Chapter 5.2]*

A Composition Root is a single, logical location in an application where modules are composed together. You can find a detailed description of what a Composition Root is in [this excerpt](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) from the book.

In respect to your question, the important part of the Service Locator definition is: "outside the Composition Root". In other words, accessing an unbounded set of Volatile Dependencies from *within* the Composition Root is fine, and is not an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern. Accessing them *outside* the Composition Root, however, is an anti-pattern.

So to answer your question, you can safely let your factory depend on the container or an abstraction that resolves an unbounded set of dependencies, as long as your factory *implementation* is part of the Composition Root.

You can achieve this by placing the factory's abstraction close to your application logic, while you create a factory implementation in the start-up assembly of your application.

> Users will need access to a few extra dependencies for their events so I've given them access to the IServiceProvider, What is the downside of using the Service Location Pattern During Registration?

If the code that depends on the `IServiceProvider` is *not* part of the Composition Root, they use the Service Locator anti-pattern, and this should be prevented. Main problems with the Service Locator anti-pattern are:

- The module drags along the Service Locator as a redundant Dependency.
- The module makes it non-obvious what its Dependencies are. This makes such module harder to test, obscures the fact that a class might be too complex, and makes it harder to verify the correctness of the dependency graph, since dependencies are fetched lazily.

Instead, you should let those users define their dependencies as constructor arguments.

Comment: this is a partially in the composite root,  I’m allowing users to dynamically configure services from the startup, my main goal is to have them avoid creating classes in the first place.

Comment: everything you said makes sense, the only part I’m missing is whether, configuration from the startup counts as part of the composite root?

Comment: I guess it’s probably not okay sense the user has access to it, for now I’ll just make a few extra generic methods whose generic params will just be dependencies to grab from the service provider, to abstract usage too only be a part of the library code

Comment: Your Composition Root is the logical location where you compose your object graphs. If you define mappings between abstractions and implementations in your configuration, that configuration file is part of the Composition Root.

Comment: Note that you should prevent having any call to a service that can resolve *any* dependency outside the composition root. Even an `Func<Type, object>` can be a Service Locator when used *outside* the Composition Root. Whether that is inside a library or in your main application doesn't really matter. That's still a Service Locator.

Comment: thanks so in this case, it's part of the CompositionRoot.  Would you recommend leaving exposure to the ServiceProvider in the case above, Or should I abstract it away completely and just create a method `AddCreateEvent<TDTO, TDEP1, TDEP2, TDEP3>` and if they need more dependencies than that, they'll have to register a class instead of using dynamic configuration

Comment: It's not very clear to me how your framework works, but it would be good to read Mark Seemann's advice on how to build a [DI-Friendly framework](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/). Instead of having events that provide dependencies in `Func<T>` methods, define a factory abstraction that users can override to intercept the creation of your root types. In your case your root types seem like event handlers? The user can than use common practices, like constructor injection, to define their event handlers, and the event handler factory can resolve them with dependencies.